# NHibernate.MappingException: No persister

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've got a problem doing updates with a stateless session and I'm 
wondering if anyone has seen something like this. (NHibernate 3.1).

I'm basically doing the following:

```
SomeEntity e = statelessSession.Get<SomeEntity>(id); 
e.SomeProperty = "a new value"; 
statelessSession.Update(e);
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: 
  Castle.Proxies.SomeEntityProxy 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String 
  entityName) 
  at NHibernate.Impl.StatelessSessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String 
  entityName, Object obj) 
  at NHibernate.Impl.StatelessSessionImpl.Update(String entityName, 
  Object entity) 
  at NHibernate.Impl.StatelessSessionImpl.Update(Object entity)
```

The mapping -

```
class SomeEntityMap : ClassMap<SomeEntity>
{
    public SomeEntityMap()
    {           
        Table("Some_Entity");            
        Id(x => x.ID).Column("ID");         
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("NAME");
    }
```

I have stepped through in the debugger and can see that 
statelessSession.Get(id) is returning me a proxy. Is this 
correct?

anyone have any idea what is the problem ? Please share your view and suggestion.

Comment: Please can you provide the mapping for entity you are trying to update?

Comment: I have added mapping now.

Comment: I've create an issue: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-4040

Answer (score 1):

I did a test project as you outlined in your question and wasn't able to reproduce the issue. The only scenarios that I was able to reproduce the error were:

1. The location of the mappings haven't been specified when initializing the session factory, i.e. you are missing

   ```
   Fluently.Configure()
     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeEntity>());
   ```
2. One of the properties of `SomeEntity` has been marked as `lazy="no-proxy"`. More information can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nhusers/Zl2P93Max0I).